# Prove continuity of $\frac{x^3y+2xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$ using the definition

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(0,0)=0$
and
$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3y+2xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. Is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

I went to polar coordinates, 
$$
f(x,y)=g(r,t)=r^4(\cos^3t \sin t+2\cos t\sin^3t)/r^2=r^2 \cdot \textit{Small value} \to 0
$$ when $r \to 0$.

Is that a valid proof? My book uses the triangle inequality.

Comment: That is too informal, I think. If you want to be informal, it is just as easy to say that the absolute value is $\le 3r^2$.

Comment: But, yes, you can prove this using Polar coordinates